# Hibernate getting position of a row in a result set

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I need to get an equivalent to this SQL that can be run using Hibernate. It doesn't work as is due to special characters like @.

```
SELECT place from (select @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS place, time, id FROM `testing`.`competitor` JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r order by time) competitorList where competitorList.id=4;
```

My application is managing results of running competitions. The above query is selecting for a specific competitor, it's place based on his/her overall time.

For simplicity I'll only list the COMPETITOR table structure (only the relevant fields). My actual query involves a few joins, but they are not relevant for the question:

```
CREATE TABLE competitor {
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR,
    time INT
}
```

Note that competitors are not already ordered by time, thus, the ID cannot be used as rank. As well, it is possible to have two competitors with the same overall time.

Any idea how I could make this work with Hibernate?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would help if you posted a table structure with sample data. Is there a specific reason why you must use @curRow for your query?

Comment: I've added the relevant part of the schema. The reason why I use @curRow is to give me the rank of the competitor.

Comment: You mentioned "As well, it is possible to have two competitors with the same overall time." It looks like the query you have above will give an incorrect result (because a row counter does not know about ties). Am I right, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to do this, so I had to change the way I'm calculating the position. I'm now taking the top results and am creating the ladder in Java, rather than in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without a schema, but you may be able to use something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testing ts 
WHERE ts.score < $obj.score
```

where I am using the $ to stand for whatever Hibernate notation you need to refer to the live object.

Comment: for that I'd need to first know the $obj.score, thus load the object from DB. other than that, I might have several competitors with the same score/time. Using your query, it will stop at the first one, thus not giving me the correct position on the ladder. I'll add a schema to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that actually your query would give me the correct position on the ladder as all competitors with the same result should be on the same position. I might just add to only give me distinct times to make it better. If I could do this without going twice to DB would be great.

Comment: I don't believe Mysql supports windowing functions. In functions that do, you can use an order by and the window function rank() to obtain what you want in one query.